# How can I reference multi-line secrets in Github Actions?

Tags: bash, github-actions

I've been directed to "handle this programmatically" and I don't have the ability to change or add the credentials file.

Using Github Actions, I've created a workflow that needs GCloud authenticated. Unfortunately, it seems that the variable is replaced prior to the `run` commands being executed, resulting in a multi-line YAML file that produces a bunch of errors.

Here's a snippet of the YAML:

```
   # Setup gcloud CLI
    - name: Use Google Cloud Platform
      uses: GoogleCloudPlatform/github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
      with:
        version: '270.0.0'
        service_account_email: ${{ secrets.SA_EMAIL }}
        service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}

    - run: cd ui/ && pwd && npm install && npm run test
      env:
        CI: true
    - run: |
        echo ${{ secrets.GCP_AUTH_STAGING }} | gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=-
        gcloud container clusters get-credentials staging --region northamerica-northeast1 --project example-staging
        cd ui/ && pwd && npm run build && cd build/ && gsutil cp -r . gs://test.example.com/
```

I've tried escaping the credentials with something like `CREDS=$( ${{ secrets.GCP_AUTH_STAGING }} )` but this just results in another multi-line problem. I believe the YAML variable is replaced prior to being executed, instead of being passed as an env.

If anyone has a command-line solution it would be much appreciated!

Please note I'm aware that there's a service account/key in the YAML as well but I cannot access it.

Comment: What's the error, see if you need to escape `$` sign for a variable (so that it won't expand early on). I recall in `ansible`, you can simply just use: `{{ variable }}`

Comment: `command not found: ***` ...the github logs protect actual content from secrets. I *do* want the variable to be expanded, the problem is that github replaces the YAML variable prior to processing the YAML file in its entirety. Hmm, I wonder if I actually need a YAML escape solution instead of command-line

Answer (score 12):

Using base64 we encode the service account JSON and pass it via environment variable. Then before calling the `activate-service-account` decode using the shell script.

**Sample code:**

```bash
echo "$GCP_CREDENTIALS" > gcp_credentials_enc.json
cat gcp_credentials_enc.json | base64 -d > gcp_credentials.json
```

Comment: Is it still the only answer till today?

Answer (score 9):

You need to ensure it's handled correctly either at the YAML level (can be done using `|`):

```
  - env:
      SSH_KEY: |
        ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
```

Or if a command in bash ensure it's correctly interpreted. For example if you are doing:

`echo ${{ secret.SSH_KEY }}`

this should instead be quoted so it becomes:

`echo "${{ secret.SSH_KEY }}"`